# Java hashCode of a POD?

Tags: java

I have this simple class

```
public class Position{
   int x;
   int y;

   Position(int x,int y){...}

   public int hashCode(){
    Integer ix = this.x;
    Integer iy = this.y;
        
    return 13*iy.hashCode() + 43*ix.hashCode();
   }
}
```

Im storing instances in a `hashMap`, but then can't retrieve them. I fear its the `hashcode` implementation. Is there any way to implement it when x and y are not Objects?

Comment: So what was it? Missing equals?

Comment: a combination of crappy decisions involving a crappy equals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That you cannot retrieve them has nothing to do with your hashCode implementation.

As Integer#hashCode just returns its value, you could simplify it as

```
 public int hashCode(){
      return 13*iy+43*ix;
 }
```

Are you changing ix and iy after putting the object into the map? That is a big no-no and totally screws up the hashtable.

Also, you need to define `Position#equals` as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have a guess: did you override `equals` method as well? In Java, when you implement one, you should implement another.

In particular, if you use `Position` instances as keys, `HashMap` will compare them with `equals`. Otherwise, two keys can accidentally have same hash, but different values.

From `HashMap#get`

```
if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k)))
            return e.value;
```

Comment: I don't think to override 'equals' method in this case, as Object.equals() is OK for the case:)


I agreed with Thilo: It's wrong to change ix and iy after putting the object into the map

Comment: @Shenguanl Lu: How is Object.equals() okay?

Comment: Rule says: if a.equals(b) then a.hashCode()==b.hashCode() is a must. So Object.equals() and Position.hashCode() are complied with it

Comment: But as a hash key, you would want to have Position(1,1) being equal to Position(1,1), even if they are different objects.

Comment: @Thilo: I know your idea, you're right.
if equals() isn't overridden, the argument of HashMap.get() needs a identical reference of map key.